How to use Flow in iOS from my kotlin repository?
In my KMM app, I have my kotlin shared code with this method:
fun getUserProfile(): Flow<UserInfo?> =
        firestore.collection("UserInfo").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).snapshots
            .mapLatest { user ->
                user.data<UserInfo>()
            }
            .catch { ex ->
                println("Something wrong")
            }

The way that I call the method in the android:
ViewModel:
val userInfo = repo.getUserProfile().catch { println("no User found") }

UI:
usersViewModel.userInfo.collectAsState(null).apply { }

I want something similar for my iOS SwiftUI, I want a simple call:
func getUserInfo(){
 }


Directly, manually consuming a Flow is not great. There are two main library options. We publish SKIE, which I would recommend. Specifically for what you want to do, take a look at this: https://skie.touchlab.co/features/flows-in-swiftui.
Kotlin
class SharedViewModel {
    
    val counter = flow<Int> {
        var counter = 0
        while (true) {
            emit(counter++)
            delay(1.seconds)
        }
    }

    val toggle = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
}

Swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    let viewModel = SharedViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        // Observing multiple flows with attached initial values, only requiring a single view closure for content.
        Observing(viewModel.counter.withInitialValue(0), viewModel.toggle) { counter, toggle in
            Text("Counter: \(counter), Toggle: \(toggle)")
        }
    }
}

The other option is https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines.
SKIE actually augments the output of the Kotlin compiler, generating Swift and compiling into the framework. KMPNC is more of a standard library, but requires more direct management of lifecycle, etc.

I cant add more libraries since the job on the android side is already done. Do you know some alternative like CommonFlow? Also, please use the code from the question.

The library only needs to be on iOS.
